# undefined reference to `rwhite::circle::draw() const'

Tags: c++

I can't tell why my it cannot find this method;

My circle.h file

```
namespace rwhite {

class circle : public shape {
public:
//Draw shape
    void draw() const;
}
```

My circle.cc file;

```
using namespace std;

namespace rwhite{
    void circle::draw() const{
        cout << "You've drawn a Circle with a position of " << _center << " and a radius of " << _radius << ".\n";
    }
}
```

My main method;

```
using namespace std;

#include "shape.h"
#include "circle.h"
#include "rectangle.h"
#include "triangle.h"
#include "shape-utils.h" // Contains answers to Q-3,4,6,7

using namespace rwhite;

int main(void) {
    circle    c;

    c.draw();
}
```

I get this error message - undefined reference to `rwhite::circle::draw() const'

Also, when I'm compiling the circle.cc file alone i get this error message;

e:.....\libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Comment: How do you compile that files?

Comment: U must do that by `gcc circle.cc main.cc` then it will link it together.

Comment: Is there no way of doing it in something like code::blocks?!?

Answer (score 2):

First of all the method `draw()` isn't public, try doing the following:

```
class circle : public shape {
public:
  void draw() const;
}
```

When you don't specify any access specifier it will be *private*.

You get the undefined reference error because the linker can't find the symbol. What are you using to compile the files with and how? You need to compile *all* the files and link together all the object files afterwards.

Comment: Sorry I've just summarised the files, I've actually put the public before this method!!

Comment: In the code above `draw()` does not have public access specifier. But you mean that you forgot about it?

Comment: Sorry, I should of been more clearer! I've made it public in my class I just didn't include that bit of the code in my post, I just wanted to see why it wasn't picking up my method, didn't think to include that in the post!

Comment: @r0bb077 On StackOverflow you can edit your questions--so you can change it to include the `public:` specifier.  (Also: when you reduce your code down like this, be sure to test the reduced version to make sure it still has the same problem...otherwise the source of the issue may be in the part you omitted.)